# What is the C++ function to raise a number to a power?

Tags: c++, math, pow, exponentiation

How do I raise a number to a power?

```
2^1

2^2

2^3
```

etc...

Comment: The title was misleading. This is about powers in general, not just squaring. I edited it and fixed it.

Comment: If it's about powers of 2 in general, use <<.

Comment: Yes, that will work for *integers* . . .

Comment: Specifically, integers *of a limited domain*. Even just 2^70 will overflow an integer (but a float can represent it *precisely*)

Answer (score 183, accepted):

pow() in the cmath library. More info [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow).
Don't forget to put `#include<cmath>` at the top of the file.

Comment: What is the difference between `cmath` and `math.h`?

Comment: @MikeSmith Use `cmath` in C++, `math.h` in C. `math.h` gets less support nowadays than `cmath`. Further reading: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10694255/11942268

Answer (score 109):

`std::pow` in the `<cmath>` header has these overloads:

```
pow(float, float);
pow(float, int);
pow(double, double); // taken over from C
pow(double, int);
pow(long double, long double);
pow(long double, int);
```

Now you can't just do

```
pow(2, N)
```

with N being an int, because it doesn't know which of `float`, `double`, or `long double` version it should take, and you would get an ambiguity error. All three would need a conversion from int to floating point, and all three are equally costly!

Therefore, be sure to have the first argument typed so it matches one of those three perfectly. I usually use `double`

```
pow(2.0, N)
```

Some lawyer crap from me again. I've often fallen in this pitfall myself, so I'm going to warn you about it.

Comment: `int N; pow(2.0, N)` would still be ambiguous:

`could be 'pow(double,int)'
 or       'pow(double,double)'` :-/ → cast

Comment: @marvin i recommend to read my answer before adding a comment. i explained that it does not give an ambiguity.

Comment: I recommend to read my comment before adding a comment. ;-) I explained that it DOES give an ambiguity. (Compiler of VS2008)

Comment: @Marvin: Visual C++ 2010 Express has no problem with `std::pow(2.0, 3)`.

Comment: @Marvin since i've grown more arrogant over time, I'm going to reply once again: You did *not* say "... is rejected as ambiguous by compiler ..." but you said "... would still be ambiguous: ...", for which you provided no backing-up. Hinting at compiler behavior may be a backup, but if I've shown independently from compilers from first principles (the spec itself) that this is not ambiguous, I've got the higher ground. Alas, C++ compilers may have bugs.

Comment: I want to perform float number as Base and float number as exp without using pow() function manually. Is there any way.

Comment: I think that also `pow(2, N)` is unambiguous since C++11, because there is a template function receiving any arithmetic type as parameters.

Answer (score 51):

In C++ the  "^" operator is a bitwise XOR.  It does not work for raising to a power. The x << n is a left shift of the binary number which is the same as multiplying x by 2 n number of times and that can only be used when raising 2 to a power, and not other integers. The POW function is a math function that will work generically.

Comment: Specifically, `1 << n` is the same as raising 2 to the power n, or `2^n`.

Comment: For those who did not get why the "1" in `1 << n` in @AshishAhuja comment, it's because the series goes like this

    `1 << 0 = 1` since `2^0 = 1`;

    `1 << 1 = 2` since `2^1 = 2`;

    `1 << 2 = 4` since `2^2 = 4`

and so on...

Comment: the "^" operator is a bitwise exclusive OR.. not a bitwise OR. That would be the | operator

Answer (score 16):

Use the pow(x,y) function: [See Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/pow/)

Just include math.h and you're all set.

Answer (score 16):

You should be able to use normal C methods in math.

`#include <cmath>`

`pow(2,3)`

if you're on a unix-like system, `man cmath`

Is that what you're asking?

Sujal

Answer (score 13):

While `pow( base, exp )` is a great suggestion, be aware that it typically works in floating-point.

This may or may not be what you want: on some systems a simple loop multiplying on an accumulator will be faster for integer types.

And for square specifically, you might as well just multiply the numbers together yourself, floating-point or integer; it's not really a decrease in readability (IMHO) and you avoid the performance overhead of a function call.

Comment: And yeah, this may fall into the "premature optimization" category, but I always find it good to be aware of things like this -- especially if you have to program in limited-resource environments.

Answer (score 11):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but if you like working with QT, they have their own version.

```
    #include <QtCore/qmath.h>
    qPow(x, y); // returns x raised to the y power.
```

Or if you aren't using QT, cmath has basically the same thing.

```
    #include <cmath>
    double x = 5, y = 7; //As an example, 5 ^ 7 = 78125
    pow(x, y); //Should return this: 78125
```

Answer (score 11):

if you want to deal with **base_2** only then i recommend using left shift operator ***<<*** instead of **math library**.

sample code :

```
int exp = 16;
for(int base_2 = 1; base_2 < (1 << exp); (base_2 <<= 1)){
    std::cout << base_2 << std::endl;
}
```

sample output :

```
1   2   4   8   16  32  64  128  256  512  1024  2048  4096  8192  16384  32768
```

Answer (score 6):

It's pow or powf in `<math.h>`

There is no special infix operator like in Visual Basic or Python

Comment: powf() is a C99 function that is not in C++.

Answer (score 6):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

double raiseToPow(double ,int) //raiseToPow variable of type double which takes arguments (double, int)

void main()
{
    double x; //initializing the variable x and i 
    int i;
    cout<<"please enter the number"; 
    cin>>x;
    cout<<"plese enter the integer power that you want this number raised to";
    cin>>i;
    cout<<x<<"raise to power"<<i<<"is equal to"<<raiseToPow(x,i);
}
```

//definition of the function raiseToPower

```
double raiseToPow(double x, int power)
{
    double result;
    int i;
    result =1.0;
    for (i=1, i<=power;i++)
    {
        result = result*x;
    }
    return(result);
}
```

Comment: Your answer should contain an explanation of your code and a description how it solves the problem.

Comment: conio.h is deprecated non standard header file don't use it.

Answer (score 6):

Many answers have suggested `pow()` or similar alternatives or their own implementations. However, given the examples (`2^1`, `2^2` and `2^3`) in your question, I would guess whether you only need to raise `2` to an integer power. If this is the case, I would suggest you to use `1 << n` for `2^n`.

Answer (score 6):

First add `#include <cmath>` then
you can use **`pow`** methode in your code for example :

```
pow(3.5, 3);
```

Which **3.5** is **base** and ***3*** is ***exp***

Answer (score 5):

```
pow(2.0,1.0)
pow(2.0,2.0)
pow(2.0,3.0)
```

Your original question title is misleading. To just *square*, use `2*2`.

Answer (score 4):

Note that the use of `pow(x,y)` is less efficient than `x*x*x` y times as shown and answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/2940800/319728.

So if you're going for efficiency use `x*x*x`.

Answer (score 2):

I am using the library `cmath` or `math.h` in order to make use of the `pow()` library functions that takes care of the powers

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

int main()
{
    double number,power, result;
    cout<<"\nEnter the number to raise to power: ";
    cin>>number;
    cout<<"\nEnter the power to raise to: ";
    cin>>power;

    result = pow(number,power);

    cout<<"\n"<< number <<"^"<< power<<" = "<< result;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use pow() function in cmath, tgmath or math.h library.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int a,b;
cin >> a >> b;
cout << pow(a,b) << endl; // this calculates a^b

return 0;
}
```

do note that if you give input to power as any data type other than long double then the answer will be promoted to that of double. that is it will take input and give output as double. for long double inputs the return type is long double. for changing the answer to int use,
    int c=(int)pow(a,b)

But, do keep in mind for some numbers this may result in a number less than the correct answer. so for example you have to calculate 5^2, then the answer can be returned as 24.99999999999 on some compilers. on changing the data type to int the answer will be 24 rather than 25 the correct answer. So, do this

```
int c=(int)(pow(a,b)+0.5)
```

Now, your answer will be correct.
also, for very large numbers data is lost in changing data type double to long long int.
for example you write

```
long long int c=(long long int)(pow(a,b)+0.5);
```

and give input a=3 and b=38
then the result will come out to be 1350851717672992000 while the correct answer is 1350851717672992089, this happens because pow() function return 1.35085e+18 which gets promoted to int as 1350851717672992000. I suggest writing a custom power function for such scenarios, like:-

```
long long int __pow (long long int a, long long int b)
{
long long int q=1;
for (long long int i=0;i<=b-1;i++)
{
q=q*a;
}

return q;
}
```

and then calling it whenever you want like,

```
int main()
{
long long int a,b;
cin >> a >> b;

long long int c=__pow(a,b);
cout << c << endl;

return 0;
}
```

For numbers greater than the range of long long int, either use boost library or strings.

Comment: Names containing `__` are reserved, you should probably pick something else.

Answer (score 1):

```
int power (int i, int ow) // works only for ow >= 1
{ // but does not require <cmath> library!=)
    if (ow > 1)
    {
         i = i * power (i, ow - 1);
    }
    return i;
}

cout << power(6,7); //you can enter variables here
```