# Transform-and-Accumulate

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, transform, accumulate

Have anybody written a C++ STL-compliant algorithm that combines `std::transform` and `std::accumulate` into a single pass algorithm supporting both the unary, binary and perhaps even (n-ary!) variant, say `std::transformed_accumulate`? I want this because I have found this pattern highly reusable in for example linear algebra for example in (l1-)norm calculations. The l1-norm calculates the sum of the absolute values of the elements.

Comment: If I am not wrong, you are asking for mapreduce.

Answer (score 11):

Uhm... My bet is that you can do that by embedding your transformation into the binary predicate, tranform the element and accumulate after the transformation.

```
struct times2accumulator {
   int operator()( int oldvalue, int newvalue ) const {
      return oldvalue + 2*newvalue;
   }
};
int r = std::accumulate( v.begin(), v.end(), 2, times2accumulator() );
```

That functor would be equivalent to:

```
struct times2 {
   int operator()( int x ) {
      return 2*x;
   }
};
std::vector<int> tmp; tmp.reserve( v.size() );
std::transform( v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter(tmp), times2 );
int r = std::accumulate( tmp.begin(), tmp.end(), 0 );
```

Of course this could be made generic, just pass the transformation functor to a generic base functor:

```
template <typename Transform>
struct transform_accumulator_t {
    Transform t;
    transform_accumulator_t( Transform t ) : t(t) {}
    int operator()( int oldvalue, int newvalue ) const {
        return oldvalue + t(newvalue);
    }
};
// syntactic sugar:
template <typename T>
transform_accumulator_t<T> transform_accumulator( T t ) {
    return transform_accumulator_t<T>(t);
}
int r = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0, transform_accumulator(times2));
```

And you could also generalize on the type in the container... or even create a more generic transform_accumulator that takes both an accumulator and a transformation functors and applies them in order. Actual implementation left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Clever... Can we perhaps simplify this using C++11 lambda expressions?

Comment: @Nordlöw: Sure, if your compiler supports them :)

Answer (score 2):

Although it may not exactly fit the original intent, `std::inner_product` is basically your binary version. You pass it an initial value, two ranges, and two functors, and it applies them as:

```
T acc = initial_value;
while (begin1 != end1) {
    acc = binary_op1(acc, binary_op2(begin1, begin2);
    ++begin1;
    ++begin2;
return acc;
```

So, for your L1 you'd do something on this general order:

```
norm = std::inner_product(input1.begin(), input1.end(), 
                          input2.begin(), input2.end(), 
                          std::plus<int>(), std::abs);
```

Only that doesn't quite work -- right now, it's trying to pass `std::abs` where you really need a binary function that combines the two inputs, but I'm not sure how the two inputs are really supposed to be combined.

`std::partial_sum` is fairly close to your unary version, except that along with accumulating a result, it (attempts to) write out each intermediate result, not just the final result. To just get the final result, you'd have to write (and pass an instance of) a kind of do-nothing iterator that just holds a single value:

```
template<class T, class Dist=size_t, class Ptr = T*, class Ref = T&>
class unique_it : public std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, T, Dist, Ptr, Ref> { 
   T &value;
public:
   unique_it(T &v) : value(v) {}
   T &operator*() { return value; }
   unique_it &operator++() { return *this; }
   unique_it &operator+(size_t) { return *this; }
   unique_it &operator++(int) { return *this; }
};

template <class T>
unique_it<T> make_res(T &v) { return unique_it<T>(v); }
```

With this, your L1 normalization would look something like this:

```
int main(){ 
    double result=0.0;
    double inputs[] = {1, -2, 3, -4, 5, -6};

    std::partial_sum(
        inputs, inputs+6, 
        make_res(result),
        [](double acc, double v) {return acc + std::abs(v);});

    std::cout << result << "\t";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks even more for relevant references to other reusable STL algorithms.

Comment: Is `std::adds<int>()` part of the standard?

Comment: @Nordlöw: Oops -- should be `std::plus<int>`. Sorry 'bout that.

Comment: If lambdas are available should I prefer using, say, `[](T x, T y) { return x+y; }` over `std::plus<T>`?

Comment: @Nordlöw: I most go with whatever's simplest. In this case, that seems to be `plus`. The exception would be if you're using a *lot* of lambdas anyway, in which case mixing in a few pre-built functors could  lead to confusion.

Answer (score 2):

As of C++17 there is also `std::transform_reduce`, which also has the benefit of being parallelizable.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform_reduce

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use some parallelism, I made a quick version using OpenMP :

```
template <class T, 
          class InputIterator, 
          class MapFunction, 
          class ReductionFunction>
T MapReduce_n(InputIterator in, 
              unsigned int size, 
              T baseval, 
              MapFunction mapper, 
              ReductionFunction reducer)
{
    T val = baseval;

    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        T map_val = baseval;

        #pragma omp for nowait
        for (auto i = 0U; i < size; ++i)
        {
            map_val = reducer(map_val, mapper(*(in + i)));
        }

        #pragma omp critical
        val = reducer(val, map_val);
    }

    return val;
}
```

It is fast but there is certainly room for optimisation, especially around `for (auto i = 0U; i < size; ++i)` I think. (But I couldn't figure how to make an iterator-only version with OpenMP, any help would be appreciated!).

On a quick test with 1000000 elements array, and the computation iterated 1000 times to have a mean value, I made some comparisons.

**Version 1 :**

```
for (auto i = 0U; i < size; ++i)
    val += std::pow(in[i][0], 2) + std::pow(in[i][1], 2);
```

score when compiled with:

- `g++` : 30 seconds
- `g++ -O3` : 2.6 seconds

**Version 2 :**

This version is the most optimized for this computation I think. (It gives the best result).

```
#pragma omp parallel reduction( + : val )
{
    double map_val = 0.0;

    #pragma omp for
    for (int i=0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        map_val += std::pow(in[i][0], 2) + std::pow(in[i][1], 2);
    }

    val += map_val;
}
```

- `g++ -O3` : 0.2 seconds (it's the best one)

**Version 3**

This version uses the MapReduce_n function template I shown earlier :

```
double val = MapReduce_n(in, size, 0.0, [] (fftw_complex val)
    {
        return std::pow(val[0], 2.0) + std::pow(val[1], 2.0);
    }, std::plus<double>());
```

- `g++ -O3` : 0.4 seconds, so there is a slight overhead for not using directly the OMP reduce directly. However, it doesn't allows custom operators, so at one point you (sadly) have to trade speed for genericity.

Comment: Nice! One thing though...is `std::pow(x, 2.0)` really faster than `x*x`?!

Comment: According to this one should be inlinee to the other http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321170/is-there-any-advantage-to-using-powx-2-instead-of-xx-with-x-double. However I prefer to write `pow` because it looks more like the formula, and because there is a lot of other `pow` in the software I took this source-code from, so the "looks" are consistent.

Answer (score 1):

I am surprised noone said how to do this with Boost.Range:

```
accumulate(v | transformed((int(*)(int))&std::abs), 0);
```

where v is a [Singe Pass Range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/concepts/single_pass_range.html) (ie, any STL container). The abs overload has to be specified, otherwise this would be as elegant as Haskell.