# When not to use pow()

Tags: c++

Today, my colleague berated me for using `pow(x, 2.0)`. He (a reasonably high-rep user on this site) insisted I wrote `x * x` as he claimed it would be faster and clearer

But why? Wouldn't `pow` know to optimise anyway? Surely my approach is clearer?

Comment: `x` is a double. Context is in a `for` loop.

Comment: Don't take his word, benchmark!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321170/is-there-any-advantage-to-using-powx-2-instead-of-xx-with-x-double might be helpful

Comment: I think it's more a thing of "When **to** use pow()". For example, if you needed `x * x * x * x * x`, it's far easier to read `pow(x, 5)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May I suggest one thing? `pow( x, 2.0 )` may be as fast as `x * x` when you have good compiler and proper optimization level. This will *NOT* be faster, though. It may be slower. For that particular reason I would still do `x * x`.

Answer (score 1):

If being clear is the utmost criteria (and it probably should be), I'd argue that `squared(x)` is even more readable than either `pow(x, 2.0)` or `x*x`. That's a trivial function to write, and you can use whichever implementation benchmarks to be fastest on your compiler and machine.

```
inline double squared(double x) { return x*x; } // or return pow(x, 2.0);
```

Comment: clear is the most important thing here. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Probably they want to say that calling pow(x, 2.0) implies stack operations to save arguments and registries, and program counter movements, so it is better and simpler to do x*x if you have to compute x^2. But I think that is a very extreme optimisation.

Comment: It's not as extreme an optimization as you might think. `pow` is already a special case that can often be replaced by an [intrinsic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_function) that incurs no calling overhead. If the compiler does that, it's a very simple check to see if the second parameter is a constant 2.0.

Comment: But We don't know how the compiler works in this cases. Do you?

Comment: I've never tested this particular case to see if it's optimized, because I've never needed to. I was just pointing out that it's not impossible. I've seen even more drastic optimizations before.