# Unary operator in C or C++ for the second power of a number

Tags: c++, c, double, cmath, unary-function

Given a `double x`, it is known that it is more efficient to use `x*x` instead of `pow(x,2)`. Imagine for simplicity that we have to calculate the square root of `x`: as it is a unary operation, for this purpose we have `sqrt(x)`. Now, also raising `x` to the second power is a unary operation, but we have nothing like (as far as I know) `pow2(x)`.

I implemented my own `pow2` as:

`inline double pow2(double a){return a*a;}`

which should be still better than `pow(a,2)`, but it is based on the `*` operator that is not unary.
How to implement a genuine unary implementation of `pow2`? Would it be the most efficient way to obtain the second power of a `double`?

NOTE: I am aware of the fact that every real power of a positive real is an unary operation and that it is nonsense to define an infinite number of `pow2`, `pow3`, `pow3.14`... from the practical point of view I'm very happy with `pow(double, double)`.

Comment: Are you sure [about the efficiency claim?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25170731/1708801)

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/gmj1nn Not really surprising.

Comment: For example here (about the efficiency claim): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321170/is-there-any-advantage-to-using-powx-2-instead-of-xx-with-x-double

Comment: Visual studio, on the other hand, https://godbolt.org/z/U95PKq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "it is more efficient to use `x*x` instead of `pow(x,2)`"

Not certainly *more* efficient.  It might be the same.  C allows analyze-ability of such functions like `pow()` and both may emit the same code.

A compiler may not analyze your `pow2()` and create sub-optimal code as compared to `pow(a,2)`.

If truly concerned, profile your code.  Yet what is *best* on one platform may differ on others.

> How to implement a genuine unary implementation of pow2?

`inline double pow2(double a){return a*a;}` is OK.

> Would it be the most efficient way to obtain the second power of a double?

"most efficient" --> I suggest no function, just `x*x`.

---

Also note that C allows FP to evaluate at higher precision that required.  Research [`FLT_EVL_METHOD`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/climits/FLT_EVAL_METHOD).    The goal for *most efficient way to obtain the second power of a double* with a function may defeat overall performance.