# Kaprekar Number between given range

Tags: c++

I'm trying to print all Kaprekar Numbers between Given Range

As input the range is between **--> 1 to 99999 <--**

The Expected Output :

**1 9 45 55 99 297 703 999 2223 2728 4950 5050 7272 7777 9999 17344 22222 77778 82656 95121 99999**

but I got this output :

**1 9 45 55 99 297 703 999 2223 2728 4950 5050 7272 7777 9999 17344 22222**

I stay miss 3 output any idea I'm using C++.

My code :

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <cmath>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::pow;

int b = 0, a = 0;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    
    int lower, upper, count = 0;
    cin >> lower >> upper;
    
    for (int i = lower; i <= upper; i++) {
        
        int n = i, digits = 0;
        while (n != 0) {
            digits++;
            n /= 10;
        }
        n = pow(i, 2);
        digits = pow(10, digits);
        b = n % digits;
        a = (n - b) / digits;
        if (a + b == i) {
            cout << i << " ";
            count++;
        }
        digits = 0;
        a = 0;
        b = 0;
    }
    
    if (count == 0) cout << "INVALID RANGE";
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/)

Comment: `pow(i, 2)` doesn't fit into an `int` for `i == 77778` (in fact, for any value greater than `46340`). Your program exhibits undefined behavior by way of integer overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the variables used in the posted snippet are of type `int`, which is probably<sup>1</sup> not enough big to store the squares of all the possible input values, so that, as note by [Igor Tandetnik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1670129/igor-tandetnik) in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73921009/kaprekar-number-between-given-range#comment130524273_73921009)

> Your program exhibits undefined behavior by way of integer overflow.

Using a wider type, like `long long`<sup>2</sup> or `int64_t` should fix the program.

I'd also avoid the use of `std::pow`, which returns a `double`, when exact integer arithmetic is needed<sup>3</sup>.

The followig snippet implements a slightly different algorithm<sup>4</sup>.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  long long int lower{ 1 };
  long long int upper{ 99'999 };

  int base{ 10 };
  
  for (auto i = lower; i <= upper; ++i)
  {
    auto n{ i * i };
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaprekar_number
    /* "a natural number in a given number base is a p-Kaprekar number if the
        representation of its square in that base can be split into two parts,
        where the second part has p digits, that add up to the original number."
    */
    auto b{ n % base };        // So, let's calculate those two parts directly.
    auto a{ n / base };
    auto power{ 1ll };
    
    while ( a >= i ) { 
      power *= base;
      b += (a % base) * power;    // Add one digit to b.
      a /= base;                  // Remove one digit from a.
    }

    if (a + b == i) {
      std::cout << i << ' '; 
    }
  }
  std::cout << '\n';
}
```

---

<sup>1) See e.g. [What does the C++ standard state the size of int, long type to be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/what-does-the-c-standard-state-the-size-of-int-long-type-to-be)</sup>

<sup>2) note that a `long` may be as wide as an `int` in certain environments.</sup>

<sup>3) See e.g. [Why pow(10,5) = 9,999 in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704195/why-pow10-5-9-999-in-c) and [Is there any advantage to using pow(x,2) instead of x*x, with x double?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321170/is-there-any-advantage-to-using-powx-2-instead-of-xx-with-x-double)</sup>

<sup>4) https://godbolt.org/z/1G9of49xb</sup>