# OpenMP parallelization is highly inefficient

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp, numerical-methods, numerical-computing

I'm trying to numerically solve a 2-D Poisson equation with around a 200x200 grid. I'm trying to implement the diagonal method to enable parallelism:

```cpp
#include <math.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int xf = -1;
int xl = 1;
int yf = -1;
int yl = 1;

double delta = 0.01;

double q(int i, int j) {
  return (4 - 2 * (pow(xf + j * delta, 2) + pow(yl - i * delta, 2))) *
         pow(delta, 2);
}

double actual(double x, double y, int n) {
  return (pow(x, 2) - 1) * (pow(y, 2) - 1);
}

double error(double **mk, double **new, int n) {
  double sum1 = 0;
  double sum2 = 0;
  double mf;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
      mf = mk[i][j];
      sum1 += pow(mf, 2);
      sum2 += pow(mf - new[i][j], 2);
    }
  }
  return pow((double)sum2 / sum1, 0.5);
}

int main(void) {

  int n = (xl - xf) / delta + 1;

  double **phiactual = (double **)malloc(n * sizeof(double *));
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    phiactual[i] = (double *)malloc(n * sizeof(double));

  double **phi = (double **)malloc(n * sizeof(double *));
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    phi[i] = (double *)malloc(n * sizeof(double));

  int i, j, d;

  int iter;
#pragma omp parallel shared(phi, phiactual, delta)
  {
    iter = 0;
#pragma omp for collapse(2)
    for (int q = 0; q < n; ++q) {
      for (int w = 0; w < n; ++w) {
        phiactual[q][w] = actual(xf + w * delta, yl - q * delta, delta);
      }
    }

    while (error(phiactual, phi, n) > 0.01) {
      for (int g = 0; g < 2 * n - 5; ++g) {
        if (g < n - 3) {
          i = 1;
          j = g + 1;
          d = g + 1;
        } else {
          i = g - n + 4;
          j = n - 2;
          d = 2 * n - 5 - g;
        }

#pragma omp for
        for (int k = 0; k < d; ++k) {
          phi[i][j] = 0.25 * (((double)(phi[i + 1][j] + phi[i][j + 1] +
                                        phi[i - 1][j] + phi[i][j - 1])) +
                              q(i, j));
          ++i;
          --j;
        }
      }
      iter++;
    }
#pragma omp single
    printf("%i\n", iter);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    free(phi[i]);
  free(phi);

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    free(phiactual[i]);
  free(phiactual);

  return 0;
}
```

The serial code takes 1m12s, while the parallel version just runs indefinitely. I used the schedule clause to try tuning the cache catches, but it does not help too.

The smaller version(20x20 grid) with `schedule(dynamic,1024)` works, but this essentially just makes it parallel.

I'm not sure where this inefficiency arises. Comments on the efficiency of serial code are also welcome.

Comment: I don't see any OpenMP in your posted code. But I would replace all calls of the form `pow(x,2)` (of which there are multiple) with `x * x`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch there's `#pragma omp`s in there, but they were hard to spot because the author didn't use any code indentation.

Comment: Hey DatBoi, I let my editor format your code. Do that yourself! Writing code without using your code editor's abilities to represent logical structure by visible indentation is really really really asking for trouble. Developer teams do instantly reject unformatted code – too hard to read, and also, it's very likely that there's subtle bugs in there because the programmer can't see the structure they've *actually* built (instead of what they *intended* to build).

Comment: @MarcusMüller thanks for the heads up! Will keep that in mind here on out. Also, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6321170/13331229)

Comment: hm, your code runs in 2.8 s for me, without openmp, and using the incredibly inefficient `pow(x, 2)` instead of `x*x` (but hint, setting your compiler to highly optimize will recognize `pow(…, 2)` and replace it with `… * …`, anyways). Are you sure this is really something you want to throw openMP at rather than optimizing your single thread performance?

Comment: The next thing you should really do is have exactly **zero** global variables. I bet your bug in openMP parallelization lies with you forgetting some shared state. Simply don't. You can write C from 2011, no need to use global variables like this was C from before 1989.

Comment: @MarcusMüller thanks for the hints, I'll fix them and report the updates soon!

Comment: also, hint: minimal profiling (and also, looking at your code) tells us that your `error` function takes up a lot of time, compared to the actual calculations. Maybe check less and rather do a few extra iterations.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I implemented the Frobenius norm because it represented the error the best. Do you have anything else on your mind?

Comment: note that my comment regarding no global variables does not extend to constants, but these should be declared as such, and not as mutable integers or doubles.

Comment: @DatBoi nothing wrong with the Frobenius norm, everything wrong with checking it every iteration instead of only every 100 iterations or so. It takes up about as much time as your phi calculation! That's stupid!

Comment: If I replace your `while(norm > 0.01)` with a simple `while(iter < 18000)`, I get a speedup from 2.8 s to 2.0s. If I replace your `i++; j--` in your inner for loop with a `idx1 = i + k; idx2 = j - k` and the indices in `phi[…][…]` accordingly, I reduce the time from 2.0 s to 0.9 s. Probably because this allows the compiler to recognize the linear addressing and avoid unnecessary loads for every new `k`.

Comment: @DatBoi Have you actually *profiled* your code and *identified* the performance bottlenecks?  If you haven't, you're probably wasting your time and effort trying to make your code run faster.  Compilers optimize, and CPUs are deeply pipelined and run multiple instructions at a time.  How you write most of your code will have almost **zero** measurable impact on performance, and you aren't likely at all to be able to identify just by looking at the code which operations are the bottleneck(s).  And **what** code bottlenecks performance can be quite surprising.

Comment: @AndrewHenle many new terms! I learnt about gprof and it turns out that theres an insane number of `q` calls!! I think I should pre-set an array for `q` values!

Comment: Before thinking about about performance, you should ensure that the OpenMP version give the same results as the serial verison (and I doubt it does).

Comment: @PierU As I noted in the post, it doesn't even run. I think theres some serious scope blunders

Comment: "does not run" --> not the same results. Your OpenMP version is not correct.

Comment: On such on code, the only thing that can be easily parallelized AND that is worth parallelizing are the double loop on `q` and `w`in the main, and the double loop on `i` and `j` in `error()`. Still, on a 200x200 grid the maximum expected speed-up won't be terrific.

Comment: I imagine you'd see at least a little improvement from using *bona fide* 2D arrays instead of arrays of pointers.

Comment: What do you expect the effect of "`#pragma omp parallel shared(phi, phiactual, delta)`" to be?  I don't think you want the whole associated block to be run by multiple threads (which is what it requests, subject to a dynamic determination of how many threads are available to run it), and the designated variables are all shared by default already.

Comment: @JohnBollinger youre right. Since theyre already declared outside, they're shared by default. I think I'll post an updated version soon! Thank you all for the inputs!

Comment: @DatBoi I noticed the `q` calls (before I saw your comment) and I added code to cache them.

Answer (score 2):

> Comments on the efficiency of serial code are also welcome.

You do *not* have `double` 2D arrays of dimension NxN. You have 1D arrays of *pointers* of dimension N to 1D arrays of `double` of dimension N.

Real 2D arrays might be faster.

Also, doing `pow(x,2)` is *slower* than `x * x`. And `pow(x,0.5)` might be `sqrt(x)`

Also, *forced* inlining some simple functions.

**Edit:** See the UPDATE below for an ~2x speedup.

---

Here is the refactored code. I added some timing/benchmarking:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define inline_always   static inline __attribute__((always_inline))

inline_always double
pow2(double x,int y)
{

#if 0
    return pow(x,y);
#else
    return x * x;
#endif
}

inline_always double
pow5(double x,double y)
{

#if 0
    return pow(x,y);
#else
    return sqrt(x);
#endif
}

int xf = -1;
int xl = 1;
int yf = -1;
int yl = 1;

int N;

double
tscgetf(void)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    double sec;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&ts);

    sec = ts.tv_nsec;
    sec /= 1e9;
    sec += ts.tv_sec;

    return sec;
}

double delta = 0.01;

double
q(int i, int j)
{
    return (4 - 2 * (pow2(xf + j * delta, 2) + pow2(yl - i * delta, 2))) * pow2(delta, 2);
}

inline_always double
actual(double x, double y, int n)
{
    return (pow2(x, 2) - 1) * (pow2(y, 2) - 1);
}

double
error(int N, double (*mk)[N], double (*new)[N])
{
    double sum1 = 0;
    double sum2 = 0;
    double mf;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
            mf = mk[i][j];
            sum1 += pow2(mf, 2);
            sum2 += pow2(mf - new[i][j], 2);
        }
    }

    return pow5((double) sum2 / sum1, 0.5);
}

int
main(void)
{

    int N = (xl - xf) / delta + 1;

#if 0
    double **phiactual = (double **) malloc(n * sizeof(double *));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        phiactual[i] = (double *) malloc(n * sizeof(double));
#else
    double (*phiactual)[N] = malloc(N * N * sizeof(double));
#endif

#if 0
    double **phi = (double **) malloc(n * sizeof(double *));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        phi[i] = (double *) malloc(n * sizeof(double));
#else
    double (*phi)[N] = malloc(N * N * sizeof(double));
#endif

    int i, j, d;

    int iter;

    double tscbeg = tscgetf();

#pragma omp parallel shared(phi, phiactual, delta)
    {
        iter = 0;
#pragma omp for collapse(2)
        for (int q = 0; q < N; ++q) {
            for (int w = 0; w < N; ++w) {
                phiactual[q][w] = actual(xf + w * delta, yl - q * delta, delta);
            }
        }

        while (error(N, phiactual, phi) > 0.01) {
            for (int g = 0; g < 2 * N - 5; ++g) {
                if (g < N - 3) {
                    i = 1;
                    j = g + 1;
                    d = g + 1;
                }
                else {
                    i = g - N + 4;
                    j = N - 2;
                    d = 2 * N - 5 - g;
                }

#pragma omp for
                for (int k = 0; k < d; ++k) {
                    phi[i][j] = 0.25 * (((double) (phi[i + 1][j] + phi[i][j + 1] + phi[i - 1][j] + phi[i][j - 1])) + q(i, j));
                    ++i;
                    --j;
                }
            }
            iter++;
        }
#pragma omp single

        double tscend = tscgetf();
        printf("%i\n", iter);

        printf("ELAPSED: %.9f\n",tscend - tscbeg);
    }

#if 0
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        free(phi[i]);
#endif
    free(phi);

#if 0
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        free(phiactual[i]);
#endif
    free(phiactual);

    return 0;
}
```

---

In the code above, I've used `cpp` conditionals to denote old vs. new code:

```
#if 0
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif

#if 1
// new code
#endif
```

Note: this can be cleaned up by running the file through `unifdef -k`

---

On my system, the elapsed time for the code (in seconds):

- 7.141084219 original
- 5.819279067 refactored

---

**UPDATE:**

By adding some debug tracing, I noticed that the sequence of values from `q` is *repeated* for each iteration of the `while (error(...))` loop.

So, we can *cache* those values in an array.

Here is the updated code (compile with `-DQCACHE=1`):

```
// fix2 -- debug, mp/np row pointers, Q caching
#include <math.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#if DEBUG
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    fprintf(stderr,_fmt)
#else
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    do { } while (0)
#endif

#define inline_always   static inline __attribute__((always_inline))

inline_always double
pow2(double x,int y)
{

#if 0
    return pow(x,y);
#else
    return x * x;
#endif
}

inline_always double
pow5(double x,double y)
{

#if 0
    return pow(x,y);
#else
    return sqrt(x);
#endif
}

int xf = -1;
int xl = 1;
int yf = -1;
int yl = 1;

double
tscgetf(void)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    double sec;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&ts);

    sec = ts.tv_nsec;
    sec /= 1e9;
    sec += ts.tv_sec;

    return sec;
}

double delta = 0.01;

int qidx;                               // current q index
int qmax;                               // maximum q index
double *qcache;                         // cache pointer

double
qcalc(int i, int j)
{
    double qval =
        (4 - 2 * (pow2(xf + j * delta, 2) + pow2(yl - i * delta, 2))) *
        pow2(delta, 2);

    dbgprt("qcalc: QCALC i=%d j=%d qval=%.15e qidx=%d\n",i,j,qval,qidx);

    return qval;
}

// qprep -- initialize Q cache
void
qprep(int N)
{
#if QCACHE
    int i;
    int j;
    int d;

    dbgprt("qprep: ENTER N=%d\n",N);

    qidx = 0;

    for (int g = 0; g < 2 * N - 5; ++g) {
        if (g < N - 3) {
            i = 1;
            j = g + 1;
            d = g + 1;
        }
        else {
            i = g - N + 4;
            j = N - 2;
            d = 2 * N - 5 - g;
        }

        dbgprt("qprep: LOOP g=%d i=%d j=%d d=%d\n",g,i,j,d);

        for (int k = 0; k < d; ++k) {
            double qval = qcalc(i,j);

            // grow cache array
            if (qidx >= qmax) {
                qmax += 100;
                qcache = realloc(qcache,sizeof(*qcache) * qmax);
                if (qcache == NULL) {
                    perror("realloc");
                    exit(1);
                }
            }

            qcache[qidx] = qval;

            ++qidx;
            ++i;
            --j;
        }
    }

    dbgprt("qprep: EXIT qidx=%d qmax=%d\n",qidx,qmax);
#endif
}

inline_always double
actual(double x, double y, int n)
{
    return (pow2(x, 2) - 1) * (pow2(y, 2) - 1);
}

double
error(int N, double (*mk)[N], double (*new)[N])
{
    double sum1 = 0;
    double sum2 = 0;
    double mf;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
#if 1
        const double *mp = mk[i];
        const double *np = new[i];
#endif
        for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
            mf = mp[j];
            sum1 += pow2(mf, 2);
            sum2 += pow2(mf - np[j], 2);
        }
    }

    double err = pow5((double) sum2 / sum1, 0.5);

    dbgprt("error: err=%.15e sum2=%.15e sum1=%.15e\n",err,sum2,sum1);

    return err;
}

int
main(void)
{

#ifdef NDEF
    enum { N = NDEF };
#else
    int N = (xl - xf) / delta + 1;
#endif
    printf("N %d\n",N);

#if 0
    double **phiactual = (double **) malloc(n * sizeof(double *));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        phiactual[i] = (double *) malloc(n * sizeof(double));
#else
    double (*phiactual)[N] = malloc(N * N * sizeof(double));
#endif

#if 0
    double **phi = (double **) malloc(n * sizeof(double *));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        phi[i] = (double *) malloc(n * sizeof(double));
#else
    double (*phi)[N] = malloc(N * N * sizeof(double));
#endif

    int i, j, d;

    int iter;

    double tscbeg = tscgetf();
    double tscend;

#pragma omp parallel shared(phi, phiactual, delta)
    {
        iter = 0;
#pragma omp for collapse(2)
        for (int q = 0; q < N; ++q) {
            for (int w = 0; w < N; ++w) {
                phiactual[q][w] = actual(xf + w * delta, yl - q * delta, delta);
            }
        }

#if QCACHE
        qprep(N);
#endif

        while (error(N, phiactual, phi) > 0.01) {
            dbgprt("main: ENTER iter=%d\n",iter);
            qidx = 0;

            for (int g = 0; g < 2 * N - 5; ++g) {
                if (g < N - 3) {
                    i = 1;
                    j = g + 1;
                    d = g + 1;
                }
                else {
                    i = g - N + 4;
                    j = N - 2;
                    d = 2 * N - 5 - g;
                }

                dbgprt("main: LOOP g=%d i=%d j=%d d=%d\n",g,i,j,d);

#pragma omp for
                for (int k = 0; k < d; ++k) {
#if QCACHE
                    double qval = qcache[qidx];
                    dbgprt("main: QCACHE i=%d j=%d qval=%.15e qidx=%d\n",
                        i,j,qval,qidx);
#else
                    double qval = qcalc(i,j);
#endif
                    ++qidx;

                    phi[i][j] = 0.25 * (((double)
                        (phi[i + 1][j] + phi[i][j + 1] + phi[i - 1][j] +
                        phi[i][j - 1])) + qval);

                    ++i;
                    --j;
                }
            }
            dbgprt("main: EXIT iter=%d\n",iter);
            iter++;

            // debug stop after iteration
#if STOP
            if (iter >= STOP)
                break;
#endif
        }
#pragma omp single

        tscend = tscgetf();
        printf("%i\n", iter);

        printf("ELAPSED: %.9f\n",tscend - tscbeg);
    }

#if 0
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        free(phi[i]);
#endif
    free(phi);

#if 0
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        free(phiactual[i]);
#endif
    free(phiactual);

    return 0;
}
```

Here are some more benchmarks:

1. `orig` is the original unmodified code
2. `fix1` is the code posted above
3. `fix2` is the improved code (compiled *without* `-DQCACHE=1`)
4. `fix3` is that code with `-DQCACHE=1`

```
BEST-O0 71.180772044 1.000x orig -- original code
BEST-O0 23.221787086 3.065x fix1 -- conversion to real 2D arrays, pow2, pow5
BEST-O0 25.597060688 2.781x fix2 -- debug, mp/np row pointers, Q caching
BEST-O0 15.749082142 4.520x fix3 -- fix2 with -DQCACHE=1

BEST-O2 6.540591962 1.000x orig -- original code
BEST-O2 5.494974338 1.190x fix1 -- conversion to real 2D arrays, pow2, pow5
BEST-O2 5.080663799 1.287x fix2 -- debug, mp/np row pointers, Q caching
BEST-O2 3.229317797 2.025x fix3 -- fix2 with -DQCACHE=1

BEST-O3 5.245094514 1.000x orig -- original code
BEST-O3 5.080274417 1.032x fix1 -- conversion to real 2D arrays, pow2, pow5
BEST-O3 5.080663799 1.032x fix2 -- debug, mp/np row pointers, Q caching
BEST-O3 2.988738434 1.755x fix3 -- fix2 with -DQCACHE=1
```

Comment: I actually benchmarked the pow(x, …) vs x*x and sqrt(x), and looked at assembly: at -O3, my GCC has absolutely no qualms at optimizing the pow to a level that I can't see the difference anymore! Interesting that yours is a) much slower to begin with than my 10 year old x86_64, b) sees speedups. Are you perhaps on an ancient compiler or using `-O0` or something?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I was using `-O2` (gcc 8.3.1). My system is pre 2010, 12 GB ram. I ran each version 5 times. But, I just noticed that `firefox` is taking up ~10 GB. I'll resettle my system and rerun the tests.

Comment: ram shouldn't be a relevant issue

Comment: @MarcusMüller The excess ram usage was causing some excessive paging. I've redone the benchmarks. And, I found an approx. 2x speedup (see the UPDATE section)

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually surprised it's not worse. Look at what you ask openMP to parallelize:

```
for (int k = 0; k < d; ++k) {
  phi[i][j] = 0.25 * (((double)(phi[i + 1][j] + phi[i][j + 1] +
                                phi[i - 1][j] + phi[i][j - 1])) +
                      q(i, j));
  ++i;
  --j;
```

You ask to run the iterations of this for loop on different threads, but the calculations depend on the values from the previous iteration! (the current iteration's `phi[i+1][j]` is the next iterations `phi[i][j+1]`).

So, what you've built is an algorithm that is impossible to parallelize in this straightforward manner. It's sequential, at least in the way you stated it.

Comment: I think you're mistaken. This is the diagonal implementation of the Gauss Seidel. The for loop being parallelized are elements along the same diagonal, whose values are independent of each other.

Comment: not in your code, they aren't.

Comment: `g` determines the diagonal number. `d` determines the number of nodes in the `g`th diagonal. Initial `i,j` have piecewise definitions accordingly. I dont spot a mistake here. It also gave the same result as the row-wise iterator, which unfortunately isnt parallelizable

Comment: I pinpointed the problem in my answer…

Comment: you explicitly serialize the calculation of at least the indices, and you use these serially calculated indices to do lookups in memory that the compliler can't know you've accessed or not. So. While the algorithmic idea might not have that problem, your implementation does!

Comment: The outer for loop and initialized values have to be serialized since they carry dependencies. Can you please elaborate on lookups? I'm pretty new to lookups and how cache works

Comment: nothing to do with cache. This is your C code: `++i; ++j;`. It literally says "to calculate the value of `i` for the next iteration, you need to finish this one". This would be no problem at all for a modern compiler and openMP, but you've decided to use these two variables to access memory that is shared between iterations. And how is your compiler supposed to know that these accesses don't conflict?

Comment: That's also the performance-killer in single-threaded execution, by the way. See my comment about `++i; ++j` under your question!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257044/discussion-between-datboi-and-marcus-muller).

Comment: `i` and `j`are shared, so `++i` and `--j` have race conditions, which is a basic no-show for OpenMP

Comment: @PierU yep, I fixed it. I forgot that I declared them before the parallel region. I put them back in so that they are private by default

Comment: This was just one part of the problem. When arriving on the loop on `k`, `i` and `j` have the same values in all the threads, and this loop consequently doesn't do what you are expecting at all.

Comment: yes, as @PierU says, you need to rewrite that loop to really resolve the data dependencies. I proposed you just keep `i` and `j` constant and use them with `k` and `-k` added as local indices, but for some reason you don't want to, DatBoi. Can't help with that.

Comment: Not only do the `k`-loop iterations depend on one another, but also, they rely on off-diagonal elements of the matrix, so the `g`-loop iterations depend on one another, too.  That means the problem cannot be solved by expanding the scope of the parallel region to the `g` loop.  I don't know this algorithm, but I'm inclined to wonder whether it is implemented correctly even for serial computation.  *Should* it really have all these data dependencies through the `phi` array?  Should it perhaps be computing a new array without modifying the original in the process, instead?

Comment: @MarcusMüller not at all! I'm very willing to make changes! This is my very first parallel implementation of an iterative method, so theres a lot to learn.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I could make matrices `phiold, phinew` to keep track of old indices and use them instead of current matrix's data. However, if you look into the Gauss-Seidel method, we use updated values whenever we have access to them. For say, when done sequentially, if you had already computed $\phi(i-1,j-1)$, you would use $\phi^{k+1}(i,j)=f(\phi^{k+1}(i-1,j-1),\phi^k(i+1,j+1))$, where `k` refers to the old values (saved by `phiold`)and `k+1` the current iteration(stored in `phinew`). If you notice, this could be achieved easily if you access the present matrix directly

Answer (score 1):

> The serial code takes 1m12s,

This is barely plausible if you are compiling without enabling optimization.  When I do that, however, I get run times on the order of 30s.  Hardware differs, of course, but that 2.5x speed difference is pretty big, so I wonder what else you may have going on.

In any event, when I enable GCC optimization level `-O3`, my execution time comes down to about 2.6s.  Performance comparisons on un-optimized binaries are pretty pointless.

> while the parallel version just runs indefinitely.

I can't confirm "indefinitely", but I do confirm that with or without optimization, compiling with `-fopenmp` increased the run time to longer than I was willing to wait.  There are numerous issues with your parallelization attempt, but the one that seems most directly related to that problems seems to be the

> ```
> #pragma omp parallel shared(phi, phiactual, delta)
> ```

directive.  **Removing that and the (then) unneeded `#pragma omp single` later in the code brings the runtime down to that of the version compiled for serial execution** for me.

I'm uncertain what your intention was with that directive, but I'm confident that it does not mean what you think it means.  The `#pragma omp parallel` part requests that the whole associated block be run by multiple threads in parallel, with the number of threads chosen dynamically (details of that choice are well defined, but irrelevant here).  You definitely do not want that.  Perhaps the `shared(phi, phiactual, delta)` part was your focus, but

1. that doesn't make sense separate from a construct that produces parallel execution, and
2. under the circumstances, `shared` is the default for these anyway, and
3. it hardly matters for `phi` and `phiactual` anyway, because the data-sharing mode applies to the pointers themselves, not the data to which they point.

Even so, your serial code is loaded down with numerous data dependencies that interfere with parallelization.  @MarcusMüller discusses some of these in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78092652/2402272).  Your inner loop also relies on shared variables `i` and `j`, which *at minimum* is likely to make the results of parallel execution differ from those of serial execution.  It may also contribute to lack of speedup -- *not that it helps to compute a wrong answer quickly!*

Overall, ***[the Gauss Seidel method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Seidel_method) is not parallelizable***. At each iteration, it relies on matrix elements to be computed in a specific order, with the computation of later elements depending on the previously-computed values of earlier elements.  There may be small parts of it that can be parallelized, such as the computation of the error term, but even the maximum possible speedup available from doing that is modest.

Comment: Thats a very neat explanation of all the issues. I have never heard about the gcc optimizer, its very cool. The pragma declaraion issues also make a lot of sense. I couldnt find any article of substance that talks about this method. I found [this github page](https://github.com/rpandya1990/Gauss-seidel-Parallel-Implementation) which has a nice diagram, which I think is intuitive.

Comment: @DatBoi, OpenMP has a lengthy, detailed specification, and a variety of shorter, easier to digest reference materials.  See `https://www.openmp.org/specifications/`.  These provide all the details you could possibly want about how to use OpenMP.  But they probably won't help you much if you're starting without a firm understanding of multi-threaded programming.  OpenMP makes multi-threaded programs easier to *implement* but not particularly easier to *design*.