# What is the effect of float (*vals)[n] = malloc(sizeof(float[n]))?

Tags: arrays, c, memory-management

The Wikipedia page explaining what a [variable-length array (VLA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) is, lists the following C99 sample code:

```
float read_and_process(int n)
{
    float (*vals)[n] = malloc(sizeof(float[n]));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        (*vals)[i] = read_val();

    float ret = process(n, *vals);
    
    free(vals);
    
    return ret;
}
```

stating

> It is possible to have VLA-like syntax with dynamic storage by using a pointer to an array.

The true C99 VLA code shown on that page is

```
float read_and_process(int n)
{
    float vals[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        vals[i] = read_val();

    return process(n, vals);
}
```

This code most likely causes the array to be located on the stack, yet that is not guaranteed (the C standard does not define where such a VLA has to be located) and also not relevant, as long as the memory is correctly freed up again once `read_and_process()` returns.

The replacement code of the Wikipedia page uses `malloc()` and `free()`, so the memory will be wherever `malloc()` reserves memory and that is typically the heap. But what effect has the `*vals` here?

My question is: How is the replacement version any different from the following code:

```
float read_and_process(int n)
{
    float *vals = malloc(sizeof(float) * n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        vals[i] = read_val();

    float ret = process(n, vals);

    free(vals);

    return ret;
}
```

Won't `process()` in the true VLA version just get a pointer to the array just as it does in the version above and has to rely on `n` telling it how many elements it can access via that pointer? So what is the point of using `(*val)[n]` and then passing `*val` instead?

### Update

Let's quickly add code for `process()`:

```
float process( int n, float * vals )
{
    // ...
}
```

How would it make any difference to this process function, which of the three versions above were used to call it? In all three cases, it gets a pointer to a bunch of float values with the pointer pointing to the very first float value. Whether those are on the stack or heap is irrelevant. In both `malloc()` versions it will be on the heap, so what is the difference between both malloc versions?

And yes, I'm aware that `typeof(vals)` is different between the Wikipedia replacement version and my replacement version but again, how would that even be relevant to the full code sample? Can you show me a code sample for `process()`, where this would play any role?

Comment: @RetiredNinja Just a typo, I accidentally deleted the asterisk during editing. To everyone who ever wrote more than hello world in C, that typo should have been obvious.

Comment: The page makes it clear the VLA is allocated on the stack. "*Because the array is declared as an automatic variable, its lifetime ends when read_and_process() returns.*"

Comment: @Schwern Yeah, the true VLA version does that, that's what I also wrote in my question, didn't I? But the `malloc()` replacement version won't as malloc does not create memory on the stack. Well, technically it could but it cannot make this dependent on the assignment of the malloc result as malloc doesn't know what you will do with the result when reserving memory.

Comment: @Mecki In your question you seem uncertain about how the allocation works. "*This code most likely causes the array to be located on the stack, yet that is not guaranteed*"

Comment: @Schwern: The fact the array has automatic storage duration and that its lifetime ends when the routine returns does not mean it is allocated on the stack. A hardware stack is often the easiest way to implement automatic objects, but it is not the only way. A C implementation that wanted to maintain a limited stack size could implement the array by inserting its own `malloc` when the array is created and a `free` when the routine completes. A C implementation specialized for an embedded environment could support fully analyzing small programs and using static storage for all objects…

Comment: … An interpreted C implementation could implement automatic objects using its own internal database. The C standard simply specifies only the periods of time during which memory is reserved for objects with the various storage durations, not how it must be implemented.

Comment: "also not relevant," - true in abstract theory; but in practice the implementation can have stack overflows and that's always something you have to bear in mind when coding on actual systems

Answer (score 3):

The construct has an advantage when passing a 2D array to a function.

I wouldn't call it a `VLA`. To me, a VLA is:

```
void
caller(int n)
{

    float arr[n];
}
```

I'd (loosely) call it, a pointer to an array with `n` elements:

```
void
caller(int n)
{

    float (*arr)[n] = malloc(sizeof(float) * n);
    float (*arr2d)[n] = malloc(sizeof(float) * n * n);
}
```

---

Without the special pointer, we would have to handle the row indexing manually:

```
void
process(int w,int h,float *arr)
{

    for (int y = 0;  y < h;  ++y) {
        for (int x = 0;  x < w;  ++x)
            arr[(y * w) + x] = (y * w) + x;
    }
}
```

---

With the special pointer, we pass along dimensions:

```
void
process(int w,int h,float (*arr)[w])
{

    for (int y = 0;  y < h;  ++y) {
        for (int x = 0;  x < w;  ++x)
            arr[y][x] = (y * w) + x;
    }
}
```

For an example, here is a recent answer of mine where I converted a `double **` pseudo implementation of a 2D array (an array of *pointers* to an array of `double`) to a "real" 2D array: [OpenMP parallelization is highly inefficient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78093573/5382650)

---

Note that we can get a similar effect with:

```
void
process(int w,int h,float arr[h][w])
{

    for (int y = 0;  y < h;  ++y) {
        for (int x = 0;  x < w;  ++x)
            arr[y][x] = (y * w) + x;
    }
}
```

But, I wouldn't call this a VLA either. It "looks like" a VLA but, to me, because it is a parameter, it is syntax to describe the pointer that is passed in by caller.

---

However, while we can use this syntax for an argument, we couldn't use this in the same function. We'd need the special syntax:

```
void
process(int w,int h)
{

    float (*arr)[w] = malloc(sizeof(float) * w * h);

    for (int y = 0;  y < h;  ++y) {
        for (int x = 0;  x < w;  ++x)
            arr[y][x] = (y * w) + x;
    }

    free(arr);
}
```

---

Suppose we didn't want to pass around three arguments to every function that wanted to manipulate the array.

We could create a `struct` with the width, height, and pointer to the array. We could then pass around a pointer to the struct:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct arr2d {
    int w;
    int h;
    float *data;
};

void
process1(struct arr2d *arr)
{

    for (int y = 0;  y < arr->h;  ++y) {
        for (int x = 0;  x < arr->w;  ++x)
            arr->data[(y * arr->w) + x] = (y * arr->w) + x;
    }
}

void
process2(struct arr2d *arr)
{
    float (*data)[arr->w] = (void *) arr->data;

    for (int y = 0;  y < arr->h;  ++y) {
        for (int x = 0;  x < arr->w;  ++x)
            data[y][x] = (y * arr->w) + x;
    }
}

void
process3(struct arr2d *arr)
{
    int w = arr->w;
    int h = arr->h;
    float (*data)[w] = (void *) arr->data;

    for (int y = 0;  y < h;  ++y) {
        for (int x = 0;  x < w;  ++x)
            data[y][x] = (y * w) + x;
    }
}

struct arr2d *
new2d(int w,int h)
{
    struct arr2d *arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr));

    arr->w = w;
    arr->h = h;

    arr->data = malloc(sizeof(arr->data[0]) * w * h);

    return arr;
}
```

---

**BENCHMARKS:**

I was curious as to how fast the various functions and indexing methods would perform. To [try to] minimize side effects, and measure only the effects of the various indexing methods, I changed the type from `float` to `int` and added a simple `idx` variable.

Here is the benchmarking code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

struct arr2d {
    int w;
    int h;
    int *data;
};

void
process1(struct arr2d *arr)
{

    int idx = 0;
    for (int y = 0;  y < arr->h;  ++y) {
        for (int x = 0;  x < arr->w;  ++x, ++idx)
            arr->data[(y * arr->w) + x] = idx;
    }
}

void
process2(struct arr2d *arr)
{
    int (*data)[arr->w] = (void *) arr->data;

    int idx = 0;
    for (int y = 0;  y < arr->h;  ++y) {
        for (int x = 0;  x < arr->w;  ++x, ++idx)
            data[y][x] = idx;
    }
}

void
process3(struct arr2d *arr)
{
    int w = arr->w;
    int h = arr->h;
    int (*data)[w] = (void *) arr->data;

    int idx = 0;
    for (int y = 0;  y < h;  ++y) {
        for (int x = 0;  x < w;  ++x, ++idx)
            data[y][x] = idx;
    }
}

void
process4(struct arr2d *arr)
{
    int w = arr->w;
    int h = arr->h;
    int (*data)[w] = (void *) arr->data;

    int idx = 0;
    for (int y = 0;  y < h;  ++y) {
        int *row = data[y];
        for (int x = 0;  x < w;  ++x, ++idx)
            row[x] = idx;
    }
}

struct arr2d *
new2d(int w,int h)
{
    struct arr2d *arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr));

    arr->w = w;
    arr->h = h;

    arr->data = malloc(sizeof(arr->data[0]) * w * h);

    return arr;
}

void
del2d(struct arr2d *arr)
{

    free(arr->data);
    free(arr);
}

double
tscgetf(void)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    double sec;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&ts);

    sec = ts.tv_nsec;
    sec /= 1e9;
    sec += ts.tv_sec;

    return sec;
}

#define DOFNC(_fnc) \
    dofnc(arr,_fnc,#_fnc)

double tscold;

void
dofnc(struct arr2d *arr,void (*fnc)(struct arr2d *arr),const char *sym)
{
    double tscbest = 1LL << 60;

    for (int iterbest = 0;  iterbest < 5;  ++iterbest) {
        double tscbeg = tscgetf();

        for (int iterfnc = 0;  iterfnc < 100;  ++iterfnc)
            fnc(arr);

        double tscend = tscgetf();
        tscend -= tscbeg;

        if (tscend < tscbest)
            tscbest = tscend;
    }

    if (tscold == 0)
        tscold = tscbest;

    printf("%.9f %.3fx %s\n",tscbest,tscold / tscbest,sym);
}

void
dotest(int w,int h)
{
    struct arr2d *arr = new2d(w,h);

    printf("\n");
    printf("dotest: w=%d h=%d\n",w,h);
    tscold = 0;
    DOFNC(process1);
    DOFNC(process2);
    DOFNC(process3);
    DOFNC(process4);

    del2d(arr);
}

int
main(void)
{

    dotest(100,50);
    dotest(50,100);
    dotest(100,1000);
    dotest(1000,100);
    dotest(10000,10);

    return 0;
}
```

I ran the benchmarks at three optimization levels: `-O0`, `-O2`, and `-O3`. The benckmarks used `process1` as the baseline. Here are the results:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
optimize -O0

dotest: w=100 h=50
0.003704862 1.000x process1
0.001824568 2.031x process2
0.001825894 2.029x process3
0.001562364 2.371x process4

dotest: w=50 h=100
0.003504016 1.000x process1
0.001778585 1.970x process2
0.001773583 1.976x process3
0.001588978 2.205x process4

dotest: w=100 h=1000
0.074285246 1.000x process1
0.036595154 2.030x process2
0.034042392 2.182x process3
0.032144590 2.311x process4

dotest: w=1000 h=100
0.070179764 1.000x process1
0.033196725 2.114x process2
0.033003560 2.126x process3
0.031031687 2.262x process4

dotest: w=10000 h=10
0.069901074 1.000x process1
0.033057440 2.115x process2
0.032876559 2.126x process3
0.028973187 2.413x process4

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
optimize -O2

dotest: w=100 h=50
0.000613288 1.000x process1
0.000389683 1.574x process2
0.000377139 1.626x process3
0.000377149 1.626x process4

dotest: w=50 h=100
0.000575807 1.000x process1
0.000363035 1.586x process2
0.000346855 1.660x process3
0.000346888 1.660x process4

dotest: w=100 h=1000
0.011875981 1.000x process1
0.007884906 1.506x process2
0.007599107 1.563x process3
0.007596456 1.563x process4

dotest: w=1000 h=100
0.011400999 1.000x process1
0.007180440 1.588x process2
0.007008333 1.627x process3
0.006975097 1.635x process4

dotest: w=10000 h=10
0.011140902 1.000x process1
0.007144627 1.559x process2
0.006928350 1.608x process3
0.006919723 1.610x process4

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
optimize -O3

dotest: w=100 h=50
0.000584456 1.000x process1
0.000534780 1.093x process2
0.000094556 6.181x process3
0.000096305 6.069x process4

dotest: w=50 h=100
0.000564249 1.000x process1
0.000377867 1.493x process2
0.000107199 5.264x process3
0.000140041 4.029x process4

dotest: w=100 h=1000
0.011978588 1.000x process1
0.010904583 1.098x process2
0.002855820 4.194x process3
0.002877185 4.163x process4

dotest: w=1000 h=100
0.011205538 1.000x process1
0.010515848 1.066x process2
0.002302689 4.866x process3
0.002076997 5.395x process4

dotest: w=10000 h=10
0.011123261 1.000x process1
0.010506258 1.059x process2
0.001983195 5.609x process3
0.001975420 5.631x process4
```

I expected `process3` to be faster and `process4` to be slightly faster yet.

What stands out:

1. The *amount* of speedup of `process3` with `-O3`.
2. For the other optimization levels, it was 1.5x-2.0x faster than `process1`.
3. For `-O3`, it was 4x-6x faster than `process1`.
4. `process4` was slightly *slower* than `process3` in some instances.

Looking at some of the disassembly, it turns out that with `-O3`, the optimizer was able to use x86 SIMD instructions with `process3` and `process4`.

I guess this just goes to show that "premature optimization" can offer some surprising results ...

Comment: But that means the Wikipedia code is just a bad sample to demonstrate VLA. They would have to also show the `process()` to be `process(int n, float (*arr)[n])`, whether that is meaningful or not. Which of course would no longer be C89, which the shown sample is but without making proper use of more complicated construct, it's just more complicated for nothing.

Comment: @Mecki: The sample isn't valid C89 because you couldn't declare a variable-length *type* in C89.  So `float (*vals)[n];` isn't a valid declaration, and `sizeof(float[n])` is ill formed.  (But you're right that it could be trivially rewritten as C89.)

Comment: @NateEldredge If `n` is a true constant, it is valid C89 as is written on the Wikipedia page. Quote:  *If in the following code, n was syntactically replaced by an integer constant expression, as if by find and replace, then the line float (*vals)[n] = malloc(sizeof(float[n])); would be valid C89 too.*

Comment: "I wouldn't call this a VLA either. It "looks like" a VLA". Being a "Variable Length Array" is not a property of on object but rather a property of object's type. So `typedef int T[n];` makes type `T` a VLA type. Thus `*vals` is VLA because it is an expression of VLA type. The actual storage is not important.

Comment: @tstanisl It's terminology See: [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1887097/5382650) There `void vlafunc(int n) { int arr[n]; }` is a VLA (a variable length array _defined_ on the _stack_). But, `void vlaptr(int n) { int (*arr)[n]; }` is a _pointer_--the actual array can live anywhere. The former (`vlafunc`) is _not_ supported in C++ and is optional in later C standards. But, _all_ of those _do_ support the latter (`vlaptr`).

Comment: @CraigEstey, `vlaptr` **is not** supported by C++. Neither VLA nor derived types are supported by C++ because they break the type system in C++. Stack allocations are just a minor detail that somehow focus all attention.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is the type of `vals`.

In replacement version, the type of `vals` is `float (*)[n]` whereas in your version the type of `vals` is `float *`. They both are different.

In your version, just try adding `1` to `vals` and it will give you the address of next element of the element it is pointing to in the dynamically allocated array, whereas adding `1` to `vals` in replacement version will give the address which is just after the `n` `float` elements.

```
float (*vals)[n]
```

`vals` is pointer to an array of `n` `float` i.e. pointer to `float [n]`.

When you de-reference `vals` i.e. `*vals`, it give `float [n]` type, which when passed as an argument to a function, converted to pointer to first element of array of `float` because of the fact that, in C, an array of type converted to pointer of type that points to the initial element of the array object (there are a few exceptions to this rule).
This the reason `*vals` is passed to `process()` function in replacement version.

For better understanding:

```
    float * vals = .....

    +---+---+---+---+---+
    |   |   |   |   |   |
    +---+---+---+---+---+
      ^   ^
      |   |
    vals  |
          |
       (vals+1)


    float (*vals)[n] = .....

vals ---+        (vals+1)---+
        |                   |
        v                   v
        +---+---+---+---+---+
        |   |   |   |   |   |
        +---+---+---+---+---+
        \__________________/
                  |
         This whole memory region treated as 
         one element to which vals pointing to.
```

Comment: *When you de-reference vals i.e. *vals, it give float [n] type, which when passed as an argument to a function, converted to pointer to first element of array of float*: But exactly the same is the case with my replacement code. The process function gets a pointer to the first float of the allocated memory array.

Comment: @Mecki The difference is all about the type of `vals` in both the functions. Since, they are different, that's why in your version, you pass `vals` but in replacement version `*vals` is passed. I have just edited my answer and added one more things. Go through it.

Comment: But what is the point of having a different type if that has no effect on the code? Why would you use a more complicated and less portable construct (my code works with every version of C, the replacement code of the Wikipedia requires C99, unless `n` is a true constant) if the whole thing has no effect and will behave exactly the same?

Comment: Okay but that means, the Wikipdia code sample is just a bad code sample because it doesn't show how using this construct is actually of any use, whereas the true VLA code is of use on its own, as it means you don't have to malloc/free anything yourself (as you have auto memory) and the compiler is likely to use stack memory (which may even be a speed advantage).

Comment: In the Wikipedia link, they have very clearly mentioned following - `It is possible to have VLA-like syntax with dynamic storage by using a pointer to an array.` and `The above technically isn't exclusive to VLAs.` There shouldn't be any confusion. It's not about good or bad, it's about what they are demonstrating in the given example.

Comment: But if you don't see how this code acts any different to my replacement code, then for someone who doesn't know what VLA even is, their sample answers nothing, as the first thing he would ask is: How is that now different from the code I posted? And your answer explains how it it is different but nowhere on the Wikipedia page that is explained as what's the point of "having a pointer to an array" if the same code works alike when having a pointer to just a memory region? There is a difference, but not in the code shown.

Comment: No such difference exists really, because the compiler makes no assumptions of the type of the chunk returned from `malloc`. This is in the territory of the unspecified/defect language feature known as "effective type", which doesn't even address arrays. All we know is a guarantee from the malloc spec that we ought to be able to access the returned chunk as "an array of thingies" with "fundamental alignment". C doesn't really tell us anything beyond that.

Comment: You could as well do `bananas* b = malloc(n*sizeof(float); ((float*)b)[i] = ...;` and that would be fine too. C has a non-existing type system when it comes to malloc.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is: How is the replacement version any different from the following code

It isn't, it just has more cumbersome syntax in this specific case. The thing with `malloc` is that the returned data has no type but guarantees that you can access the chunk of memory as an array of "stuff". The pointer type used to access that chunk is irrelevant, C only cares about the de-referenced type when doing "lvalue access".

No matter if you do `(*vals)[i] = read_val();` as in the first example or  `vals[i] = read_val();` as in the third, the type used for the lvalue access is `float` and that's all that matters in practice.

> Won't process() in the true VLA version just get a pointer to the array just as it does in the version above and has to rely on n telling it how many elements it can access via that pointer?

Since C has no bounds checking of arrays, it doesn't really matter. You can access the data out of bounds beyond `n` no matter if it's a VLA or not and C won't stop you.

> So what is the point of using (*val)[n] and then passing *val instead?

In this specific case, no point at all. Commonly we might have a parameter passed to the function, but since arrays passed as parameters get adjusted to the first element, it's all the same if we use `float* arr`, `float arr[n]` (VLA), `float arr[]` or `float arr[666]`. All of these will boil down to `float*`.

---

The advantage of the VLA notation comes when passing multi-dimensional arrays. If we have this:

```
void func (size_t x, size_t y, int arr[x][y])
```

Then the first element of this array is of type `int [y]`. A pointer to such an element is `int (*)[y]`. And so the above is equivalent to this:

```
void func (size_t x, size_t y, int (*arr)[y])
```

Either `int arr[x][y]` or `int (*arr)[y]`  allows us to access the array using readable `arr[i][j]` syntax.

If we used a flat array (as it was sometimes done in C89 which didn't support VLA), however...

```
void func (int* arr, size_t x, size_t y)
```

Then we have to access it through the cumbersome and error-prone form `arr[i*y + j]`.