# Find the some smallest negative using Dynamic memory allocation in C

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm doing my homework but there is some bugs I cannot fix
Could you please help me?
The question is using Dynamic memory allocation in C
Find the some location of smallest negative element

The Function amnn is the "thing" I cannot fix

Thank u so much

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int nhapmang (int *p,int n)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf ("Nhap vao a[%d] = ",i);
        scanf ("%d",&*(p+i));
    }
}
int inmang (int *p,int n)
{
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++) 
    printf ("   %d",*(p+i));
}

int amnn(int *p, int n)
{
    int tg,tg1;
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if (*(p+i)<0)
        {
        tg=*(p+i);
        break;
        }
    }
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
    if (*(p+i)<0 && (tg>*(p+i)))
        {
        tg1=i;
        }
    }
    printf ("\nvi tri so am nho nhat trong mang la: a[%d]",tg1);
}
int main()
{
    int *p, n,a,amnn1;
    printf ("nhap vao n: ");
    scanf ("%d",&n);
    p=(int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    nhapmang (p,n);
    printf ("\nin ma tran:");
    inmang(p,n);
    amnn(p,n);
return 0;
}
```

Input: n=5, a[0]=-9, a[1]=5, a[2]=-2, a[3]=-99, a[4]=-99
The result is a[3], a[4]

Comment: _Side note:_ Instead of (e.g.) `*(p+i)`, you can replace this with the array syntax: `p[i]` This is simpler (and preferred).

Comment: @CraigEstey sorry but, how to replace *(p+i*m +j) in two-dimensional arrays

Comment: I guess you mean a dynamic/variable 2D array (e.g.) `int arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * width * height);` where the dimensions are variable? For a fixed 2D array, you could do: `fixed[y][x];` For a dynamic array, you access this with `*(arr + y*width + x)`. This can be changed to: `arr[y*width + x]` However, for a better way, see my recent answer on using special pointers for this: [What is the effect of float (*vals)\[n\] = malloc(sizeof(float\[n\]))?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78098668/5382650)

Comment: @CraigEstey k thank u sm

Comment: If I've understood your problem correctly, it seems like this can be done on-line with `O(1)` memory by just keeping track of the leading candidate.

Comment: @Neil wdym O(1) memory

Comment: There can be any number of minima, and if you want to keep track of all of them, it's `O(n)`, but if you want to keep track of _any_ of them, whatever the problem size, it just keeps track of a minimum and doesn't really care about all the other numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I didn't understand the logic of your `amnn`.

It appears to only handle the case where there is *one* minimum value, so it would *not* handle your sample input.

I had to completely refactor your code. It is annotated:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// amnn -- find all minimum negative numbers
void
amnn(int *arr,int n)
{

    // number of indexes that contain the minimum value
    int mincount = 0;

    // list of indexes that contain the minimum value
#if ALLOC
    int *idxlist = malloc(sizeof(*idxlist) * n);
#else
    int idxlist[n];
#endif

    // current minimum value
    // start with a positive value to handle initial case
    int minval = 1;

    // loop through all array elements
    for (int curidx = 0;  curidx < n;  ++curidx) {
        int curval = arr[curidx];

        // we only want negative values
        if (curval >= 0)
            continue;

        // ignore values that are greater than the current minimum
        if (curval > minval)
            continue;

        // we have a new minimum value
        if (curval < minval) {
            // reset count of matching indexes
            mincount = 0;

            // set new minimum value
            minval = curval;
        }

        // current value is part of the set of minimum values
        if (curval == minval)
            idxlist[mincount++] = curidx;
    }

    // print results
    do {
        if (minval >= 0) {
            printf("no negative values found\n");
            break;
        }

        printf("minimum value is: %d\n",minval);

        printf("it is contained in indexes:\n");
        for (int listidx = 0;  listidx < mincount;  ++listidx)
            printf("  %d\n",idxlist[listidx]);
    } while (0);

#if ALLOC
    free(idxlist);
#endif
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> why must reset `mincount = 0` ? –
> Đinh Trọng Đạt

Perhaps, the better question to ask is:

*What happens if we do **not** reset `mincount = 0`?*

With the following sequence we would *still* get the correct answer (but only by *luck*):

```
-7 -6
```

However, **if** we have a list where the *absolute/true* minimum comes *after* a *local/false* minimum, without the reset, this will fail:

```
-6 -7
```

It will record/remember `-6`. When it sees `-7`, it will *not* remove `-6` from the list.

Here is the code modified to test this assertion:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int noreset;                            // 1=do _not_ reset count (testing)

// amnn -- find all minimum negative numbers
void
amnn(int *arr,int n)
{

    // number of indexes that contain the minimum value
    int mincount = 0;

    // list of indexes that contain the minimum value
#if ALLOC
    int *idxlist = malloc(sizeof(*idxlist) * n);
#else
    int idxlist[n];
#endif

    // current minimum value
    // start with a positive value to handle initial case
    int minval = 1;

    // loop through all array elements
    for (int curidx = 0;  curidx < n;  ++curidx) {
        int curval = arr[curidx];

        // we only want negative values
        if (curval >= 0)
            continue;

        // ignore values that are greater than the current minimum
        if (curval > minval)
            continue;

        // we have a new minimum value
        if (curval < minval) {
            // reset count of matching indexes
            if (! noreset)
                mincount = 0;

            // set new minimum value
            minval = curval;
        }

        // current value is part of the set of minimum values
        if (curval == minval)
            idxlist[mincount++] = curidx;
    }

    // print results
    do {
        if (minval >= 0) {
            printf("no negative values found\n");
            break;
        }

        printf("minimum value is: %d\n",minval);

        printf("it is contained in indexes:\n");
        for (int listidx = 0;  listidx < mincount;  ++listidx) {
            int arridx = idxlist[listidx];
            int curval = arr[arridx];
            printf("  arr[%d]=%d%s\n",
                arridx,curval,(curval != minval) ? " FAIL" : "");
        }
    } while (0);

#if ALLOC
    free(idxlist);
#endif
}

#define DOTEST(_data...) \
    do { \
        int arr[] = { _data }; \
        dotest(sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]),arr); \
    } while (0)

void
dotest(int n,int arr[n])
{

    printf("\n");
    for (int col = 1;  col <= 80;  ++col)
        printf("-");
    printf("\n");
    printf("dotest: n=%d\n",n);

    for (int arridx = 0;  arridx < n;  ++arridx)
        printf("dotest: arr[%d]=%d\n",arridx,arr[arridx]);

    printf("\nNORMAL:\n");
    noreset = 0;
    amnn(arr,n);

    printf("\nNORESET:\n");
    noreset = 1;
    amnn(arr,n);
}

int
main(void)
{

    DOTEST(-9, 5, -2, -99, -99);

    DOTEST(-7, -6);

    DOTEST(-6, -7);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the program output:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
dotest: n=5
dotest: arr[0]=-9
dotest: arr[1]=5
dotest: arr[2]=-2
dotest: arr[3]=-99
dotest: arr[4]=-99

NORMAL:
minimum value is: -99
it is contained in indexes:
  arr[3]=-99
  arr[4]=-99

NORESET:
minimum value is: -99
it is contained in indexes:
  arr[0]=-9 FAIL
  arr[3]=-99
  arr[4]=-99

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
dotest: n=2
dotest: arr[0]=-7
dotest: arr[1]=-6

NORMAL:
minimum value is: -7
it is contained in indexes:
  arr[0]=-7

NORESET:
minimum value is: -7
it is contained in indexes:
  arr[0]=-7

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
dotest: n=2
dotest: arr[0]=-6
dotest: arr[1]=-7

NORMAL:
minimum value is: -7
it is contained in indexes:
  arr[1]=-7

NORESET:
minimum value is: -7
it is contained in indexes:
  arr[0]=-6 FAIL
  arr[1]=-7
```

As above, it can help to write code that *checks* the results for validity.

To help debug programs, we can also add extra `printf` statements that can show intermediate values and progress. To keep the code small and easy to read, I prefer to use a macro:

```
#if DEBUG
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    printf(_fmt)
#else
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    do { } while (0)
#endif
```

Then, when we want to see the debug output, we compile with `-DDEBUG`. Otherwise, the program runs normally (at full speed).

Comment: sensei, I use my test case and It's return with "no negative values found"

Comment: @ĐinhTrọngĐạt I didn't test this. But, I desk checked it again after posting. I noticed a bug and posted an update: (i.e.) `int curval = arr[n];` should be `int curval = arr[curidx];`

Comment: @ĐinhTrọngĐạt You're welcome! Glad to help. Happy Programming!

Comment: Minor: `int idxlist[n];` is a problem for `n==0`.  Could use `int idxlist[n | 1];` or the like.  Of course, `n < 0` has additional issues.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I know that, but it's still ok with this test case, I dont want to make it more complex for a small homework

Comment: @CraigEstey sensei, why must reset `mincount = 0` ?

Comment: @ĐinhTrọngĐạt I've updated my answer. Have a look ...