# Why is pow(x, y, z) more efficient than (x ^ y) % z?

Tags: performance, pow

In many programming languages, the first one is faster. Why is this?

Comment: Try read this one, similar to your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940367/what-is-more-efficient-using-pow-to-square-or-just-multiply-it-with-itself

Comment: Modular exponentiation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pow(x,y,z)` is usually implemented like this (Java):

```
int pow(int x, int y, int mod) {
    long res = 1, p = x;
    while (y > 0) {
        if (y%2 == 1) {
            res = (res*p)%mod;
        }
        p = (p*p)%mod;
        y /= 2;
    }
    return (int)res;
}
```

It has O(log y) complexity which is much better comparing to O(y) in case of straightforward implementation with `y` multiplications.

Second benefit is that some languages will use long arithmetic when result of operation exceeds size of machine word (32 or 64 bits). So, in case of straightforward implementation potentially huge number `x^y` will be computed first and only then modulo `z` will be taken.