# Is `std::pow(double, int)` faster than `std::pow(double, double)`? if yes, how much faster?

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance

I saw this old question about `std::pow`: [What is more efficient? Using pow to square or just multiply it with itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940367/what-is-more-efficient-using-pow-to-square-or-just-multiply-it-with-itself)

The old question mentions `std::pow` has a variant that is `std::pow(double, int)` and some users said this version might be faster.

Is `std::pow(double, int)` faster than `std::pow(double, double)`? if yes, how much faster?

p.s. standard boilerplate disclaimer about "I already know that premature optimization is evil, but I'm asking this optimization question for academic purposes or I've already identified that line/block of code as a bottleneck"

Comment: FWIW, the overloads that took an in have been removed from C++ since C++11

Comment: Honestly, look at assembly and see.  integer power should easily translate into vectorization.  Benchmark it.

Comment: "how much faster" is really hard to answer without the dataset and/or platform you wish to perform the operations on. In other words, you'd need to benchmark it

Comment: About 42 faster.

Comment: It can be.  The C++ library implementation that I use overloads it to a trivial for-loop that uses multiply-shift.  YMMV.

Comment: If you want to know which is faster, *measure it yourself*. https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: not sure what this question is aiming for, but with integer powers you can play funny tricks like `x^n = (x^n/2 * x^n/2)` for even `n` (and similar for odds) so you basically can reduce the number of multiplications required to something around log2(n). Not sure if there is anything similar for double powers. Anyhow afaik `pow` never was really meant to be used with integers

Comment: For large exponents I would expect the same, for small ones the `int` one might be faster. Hard to know for sure, since `pow` is actually tricky to implement maintaining the precision and libraries have probably very different implementations.

Comment: @user463035818. This operation cannot be used in general on `double`s, but library might use it in easy cases (for example, when exponent is small integer) to give fast response. In general the formula `a**b = exp(log(a)*b)` would be used.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Expectation:

std::pow(double, int) is the log-reducing for loop for log(n) runtime.

std::pow(double x, double y) { exp(log(x) * y); }

Should be pretty close.

---

from comments:

- en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow (7) Since C++11, "If any argument has integral type, it is cast to double". – Bob__ Apr 11 '18 at 20:10
- My interpretation (I may be wrong and library implementers may disagree) of that statement is that until C++11, they may have had different implementations, but **since C++11, they should share the same, while the parameters are simply casted**. – Bob__ Apr 11 '18 at 20:25

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow (7) Since C++11, *"If any argument has integral type, it is cast to double"*.

Comment: @Bob__: I'm certain that's a result equivalency not the actual implementation.

Comment: My interpretation (I may be wrong and library implementers may disagree) of that statement is that until C++11, they may have had different implementations, but since C++11, they should share the same, while the parameters are simply casted.