# C program to check armstrong number

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#define pow
int main()
{
    int num,num1,num2,n,q,sum=0,no_of_digits=0;
    printf("enter  a number\n");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    num1=num2=num; //storing the entered number in another variable 'num1'
    while (num!=0) //calclating and storing the number of digits in 'digit'
    {
        num=num/10; //dividing the number by 10. int data type ignores the decimal value, giving an integer
        no_of_digits++; 
    }
    while (num1!=0) 
    {
        n=num1%10; //taking one digit at a time in n
        q=pow(n,no_of_digits);//each digit^no. of digits
        sum=sum+q; // sum of all digit^no. of digits
        num1=num1/10;
        
    }
     printf("Sum of each digit^no. of digits =%d\n",sum);
     if (sum==num2)
        printf("%d is an armstrong number\n",num2);
     else
        printf("%d is NOT an armstrong number\n",num2);

  return 0;
}
```

MY output: Sum of each digit^no. of digits =9
370 is NOT an armstrong number

Also, if i don't add the #define pow line,i get the following error.
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccGBiCYH.o: in function `main': 7.c:(.text+0xda): undefined reference to` pow'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.
I checked all the other values (num,num1,....) and they all are right. The 'pow' function doesn't seem to be working correctly.

Comment: For the undefined reference to pow, see for the millionth time https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671366/undefined-reference-to-pow-and-floor

What do you think `#define pow` does?

As for the logic here: Are you sure your computations fit in `int`s?

Comment: Your `#define pow` turns this: `q=pow(n,no_of_digits);` into this: `q=(n,no_of_digits);` which is synonymous with `q=no_of_digits;` so it is no wonder the answers were wrong. This is why we don't *guess*, especially when it comes to standard library functions. When it doubt, read the docs, see what headers contain formal declarations, and what *libraries* contain formal implementations, including the former and linking the latter respectively. And I concur with others; don't think to be using floating-point here regardless.

Comment: Abh_03, to count the number of digits, do you consider 0 to have one or zero digits?  Code here calculates zero.

Comment: Ref: [Armstrong number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_number#C).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undefined reference to \`pow' and \`floor'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671366/undefined-reference-to-pow-and-floor)

Answer (score 0):

It's required to give a definition for macro.
When you write `#define something`, you'll have to define what it will do in your code.

> A macro in C is a set of program statements that is replaced by the
> value of the macro throughout the entire program.

In your code, you wanted to write a macro for the power function.

So what a power function does?

It takes the `base` and `exponent` as parameters, then returns `base ^ exponent`.

You've to define this functionality in the macro. This is called `Function-like Macros`.

I would suggest learning more about macros before moving forward with it.

Let's get back to your code.

If you write a proper power function, I think your code will give the correct output.

**Note:** In case of both base and exponent being integer, it is safer to write your own integer power function.

Reason: [Strange behavior of the pow function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18155883/strange-behaviour-of-the-pow-function)

Here I'm giving a sample code with a very basic approach of writing a power method.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int _power(int base,int exponent)
{
    int result = 1;
    for(int i = 1; i <= exponent; i++) result *= base;
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    int num,num1,num2,n,q,sum=0,no_of_digits=0;
    printf("enter  a number\n");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    num1=num2=num; //storing the entered number in another variable 'num1'
    while (num!=0) //calclating and storing the number of digits in 'digit'
    {
        num=num/10; //dividing the number by 10. int data type ignores the decimal value, giving an integer
        no_of_digits++;
    }
    while (num1!=0)
    {
        n=num1%10; //taking one digit at a time in n
        q=_power(n,no_of_digits);//each digit^no. of digits
        printf("n: %d   no_of_digits: %d    q: %d\n", n, no_of_digits, q);
        sum=sum+q; // sum of all digit^no. of digits
        printf("Sum: %d\n", sum);
        num1=num1/10;

    }
    printf("Sum of each digit^no. of digits =%d\n",sum);
    if (sum==num2)
        printf("%d is an armstrong number\n",num2);
    else
        printf("%d is NOT an armstrong number\n",num2);

    return 0;
}
```

Please check out the following resources to learn more about Macros and pow function

- [How to Use C Macros and C Inline Functions with C Code Examples](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/04/c-macros-inline-functions/)
- [Macros and its types in C/C++](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/macros-and-its-types-in-c-cpp/)
- [Macros in C – Types and Examples](https://techvidvan.com/tutorials/macros-in-c/)
- [Define a macro which defines a pow function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69661158/define-a-macro-which-defines-a-pow-function-only-in-the-case-where-the-exponent)
- [problem with "pow" function in C++](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/1521)
- [Write a program to calculate pow(x,n)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-calculate-powxn/)
- [Writing power function for large numbers](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/writing-power-function-for-large-numbers/)