# error: invalid operands to binary expression 'float'

Tags: c++, constants, cs50, operation

Hello and sorry if this question has been asked before, but I'm working on the Josephus problem and this is the code that I´ve written.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cs50.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(void)

{
    printf("Number of people: ");
    float f=GetFloat();
    const int a=pow(2,floor(log(f)/log(2)));
    float c= 2*(f-2^a)+1;
    printf("%f\n", c);

}
```

When I try to compile it it gives me this error message.

```
clang -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c99 -Wall -Werror    Josephus.c  -lcs50 -lm -o Josephus
Josephus.c:11:20: error: invalid operands to binary
      expression ('float' and 'float')
    float c= 2*(f-2^a)+1;
                ~~~^~
```

The equation I'm trying to write in the code is c = 2(f – 2^a) + 1
Where "c" is the number I'm looking for, "f" is the number of people and "a" is the largets power of 2 smaller than f.

Sorry for any and all grammatical mistakes and my lack of knowledge of the topic, I'm new to programming. Cheers!

Comment: related/dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843304/why-is-my-power-operator-not-working and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845912/what-is-the-c-function-to-raise-a-number-to-a-power

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is `f-2^a`.  You probably expect this to subtract two to the power `a` from `f`.  Trouble is `^` is the XOR operator, and it is lower precedence than subtraction.  The compiler is treating this as `(f-2) xor a`.  The LHS of the xor is float, so the a is being promoted to float ... and xor doesn't work with floats!

The fix is either:

```
f - pow(2.0, a)
```

or:

```
f - (1u << a)
```

(but only use the latter if you are confident that `a` is in range.

Comment: This really helped, in the end I changhed a couple of things, it works and give the actual answer to the problem!