# C++ Find the present value with user inputs and exponent

Tags: c++, algorithm, exponent

I am in need of help to compute a present value. The user will input: payment amount (payamt), term (trm), and interest rate (intrte). I am having trouble computing the following equation:

present value = payment amount * ((1-(1+interest)^-term)/interest rate)

This is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()

{
int trm = 0
    ;

double intrte = 0.0
    ;

float payamt = 0.0,
    presVal = 1
    ;

char
    response = '\0'
    ;

    cout << "Would you like to compute a present value? Enter Y for yes; N for no.";
    cin >> response;

    if (response != 'Y') {
        return 0;
    }

    cout << "\nPayment Amount: $";                  //payment in $ and cents for each year
    cin >> payamt;

    cout << "\nTerm (in years): ";                  //term number of years of payments
    cin >> trm;

    cout << "\nInterest Rate (between 0 and 100): ";//interest rate
    cin >> intrte;

    cout << "\n\nThe present value for a payment amount of $" << payamt
    << " and an interest rate of " << intrte
    << "%, and a term of " << trm
    << " years is $" << presVal
    << ".\n\n" << endl;

    presVal == payamt * (1 - ((1 + intrte), (-trm)))/intrte;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what issue you are having?  Compile error?  Run time error?  And what the error messages are?

Comment: on your last line, you're comparing presVal by using "==", you should use "=" if you want to assign te formula to presVal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the C++ function to raise a number to a power?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845912/what-is-the-c-function-to-raise-a-number-to-a-power)

Answer (score 1):

When you include cmath (`#include <cmath>`), you can use the `double pow(double base, double exponent)` function to take a number to the power of another number. More info can be found here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/

Your formula becomes then:
`presVal = payamt * (1 - pow(1+intrte, -trm))/intrte;`

Comment: Thank you! I am instructed to not use any other header files other than iomanip. Can you advise? Thank you again! MUCH appreciated!

Comment: You can write your own pow function, which implements a for loop which iterates exponent times and multiplies each iteration the result (which is initialized on 1) with the base, and returns the result at the end of the function

Comment: What do you mean "write your own pow function"? Sorry, I am a beginner :)

Comment: I added cmath and the formula you provided. I am still receiving "1" as the present value. I think that is because it is defined in the variables as "presVal = 1". Do I need to create a "for" loop? Thank you!

Comment: You're still getting 1 because you're calculating your presVal after you've outputed it's value. You should first calculate it and then output it. A for loop is required for calculating the power without including cmath. (asuming trm is a natural number)

Comment: WOW! Thank you SO SO much for your help!